# Spotify conflict between smartphone and car tablet

Tags: bluetooth, spotify

I apologize for my English because it's not my native language and I hope I'm not breaking some forum rules.

I got a Samsung s21 fe and a Macrom M-an700dab, which is a car tablet with android 8.1 mounted on a peugeot  308. I have regular spotify account, only one device at time. When I'm in the car I'd like to use the tablet Spotify app and the s21 Spotify app, cause I can control that via Alexa Echo Auto. I thought in theory that can work if I use the "connect to device" Spotify feature in the smartphone app, which see the Macrom tablet like a device, allowing me to change song with the phone (therefore with the voice) and with the tablet.

The problem is that most of the time Spotify pauses the song after a few seconds, and even if I play it again it re-pauses. Then I have to close the app on the phone and use the app on the tablet or vice versa. I think what makes the conflict is the fact that the smartphone is connected to the tablet with Bluetooth.

I'd like to find a way to fix this.
I hope I have been as clear as possible, even if this problem is difficult for me to explain even in my own language. If there is something unclear or missing information, tell me and I will try to explain myself better.
Thank you in advance.